# Add object with properties prefixed by underscore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I want to add objects on my Firebase database that contains properties prefixed by `_`.

It seems only these properties are ignored when saved.

My code looks like this and is working fine:

```
.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$firebaseArray', function($delegate, $window) {
        var add, timestamp, currentUser;

        add = $delegate.prototype.$add;
        timestamp = $window.firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
        currentUser = $window.firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

        $delegate.prototype.$add = function (newData) {
            //works if remove '_'
            newData['_createdAt'] = timestamp;
            newData['_createdBy'] = currentUser;

            return add.call(this, newData);
        };

        return $delegate;
    });
})

.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$firebaseObject', function($delegate, $window) {
        var save, timestamp, currentUser;

        save = $delegate.prototype.$save;

        timestamp = $window.firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
        currentUser = $window.firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

        $delegate.prototype.$save = function () {
            //works if remove '_'
            this['_modifiedAt'] = timestamp;
            this['_modifiedBy'] = currentUser;

            return save.call(this);
        };

        return $delegate;
    });
})
```

Comment: @cartant Thanks, I didnt found that question. Found out dot is not supported by Firebase, but there is no limitation for underscore. I will edit and keep my question.

Comment: Yeah, the underscores should be valid. Do the values show up in the Firebase console?

Comment: @cartant Only if I remove underscores. I just found `$firebaseUtils.toJSON` is removing these properties.

Comment: Why did I receive two downvotes without any comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is ocurring is because AngularFire builtin method `$firebaseUtils.toJSON` removes some prefixed properties.

I solved my problem adding `.toJSON()` to my object model.

```
MyObject.prototype = {
    toJSON: function () {
        return angular.copy(this);
    }
};
```